# Samsung CLP-610ND paper jam

Tags: laser-printer, paper

At the office we have a Samsung CLP-610ND colour laser printer which has been the best printer we've ever used. After several years with never a paper jam a new problem arose where we get a paper jam every single time.

We've actually bought a new printer rather than pay for a technician to fix the Samsung but it goes through toner cartridges much faster so we're trying to see if there's a common simple problem that affects this model that we can fix ourselves.

Anyone else had this problem? (Google and the Samsung site have not come up with anything yet)

**UPDATE** more details...

- The display says "Paper jam 1" which means inside the machine.
- The paper is always just there when we open the front cover and comes out easily without a struggle.
- We can't find any obviously worn out, loose, or damaged parts. It is a little squeaky sounding since we're close to the ocean there is plenty of salt in the air but no obvious corrosion.
- Some of the small rollers are a slightly different diameter in the middle compared to the ends but maybe this is by design?
- The "jam" occurs early in the paper path, before the page gets to where the actual printing is done.
- When we power on, as part of the printer's self-test, two blank pages are fed through the system perfectly with the jam not occurring until the third page.

Comment: In what part of the printer are the jams occurring?  Are any parts in the paper path worn out, loose, or damaged?  Try examining the parts, such as the rollers, inside the printer to determine where the problem may lie.

Comment: @DragonLord: I've added a lot more info after reading your replying and fiddling with the machine a bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. As soon as I start the machine, the paper keep pulling out, and around the 3rd paper. The machine stopped with error jam1.

Could not get it fix.
But from what I've looked over internet with other samsung CLP laser printer.

It could be the sensor problem.
And I find 2 sensor located near the bottom of the paper trap (you need to upside down the printer). 1 at the top where near the heating tonner.......( I assume!)

This is the samsung support site mention about the jam1. (2nd sensor problem)
http://support-us.samsung.com/cyber/popup/pop_troubleshooting.jsp?ia_cd=N0000190&model_name=CLP-610ND

here is the Youtube video of other CLP printer having jam problem. And it can be fix by replacing the sensor. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fJHykzkfww

you can buy the sensor at samsungparts.com/
I had the look of the sensor, I believe samsung use the same senosor along on the product line which mean you can just use other CLP printer sensor.

Comment: I haven't actually verified this is the problem yet but it's the best answer by far and we'll use it when we next try to fix the printer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the printer by myself.
Anyway, I give you a **alternative quick solution** instead the hard work that I went through.

Try the front paper loader instead the bottom paper tray.
If the front paper loader is working, that mean the fault occurs at the bottom paper loader~
This could be the sensors or the other problems. 
My fault is located in the right side panel of the printer with mechanical loading parts. 
It took me half day to discover it and disassemble the machine for fixing.

Good Luck.

Comment: Actually after having little luck myself I gave the You Tube video of the fix of a different model and the written instructions I received to the handyman at my work. He took it apart a little brutally and couldn't find what was wrong and it ended up in the bin! Too bad really because the printer we replaced it with is crap in comparison and is costing them a fortune in toner.